# Refering to a column name that is a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

my problem is: I've got a table with several columns which names are numbers (e.g. i've got a column named 1. How can I refer to these columns?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: "1", is ANSI SQL, and supported by most modern dbms products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put square brackets round them like this [1], [2]
you can also do this if you have columns named after SQL keywords

Comment: Works only for SQL Server? (No dbms specified here...)

Comment: Woah. Thanks a lot, couldn't find it anywhere.. And I needed it for SQL Server.

Comment: I tested this with Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can put square braces or double quotation marks around the column names.

```
select [1], "2" from YourTable
```